# int[] cannot be converted to int[][]

Tags: java

I have an int[][] established like this:

```
public static final int[][] answers
```

But I am having issues iterating through it. I have this:

```
for(int[][] s : answers)
```

And I am getting an error that says 'incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int[][]'. They are both int[][] so I am confused why this is happening.

Comment: it has to be for(int[] s : answers)

Answer (score 1):

In an `int[][]`, each element of the 2D array is an array of integers (`int[]`).

In your for loop, you want to iterate through each element `s` in `answers`, therefore each `s` is of type `int[]`

So, what you need is `for(int[] s : answers)`, instead of `for(int[][] s : answers)`

Answer (score 0):

The type in the 'for' loop is the type of the element you'll be working on...the element FROM answers.  It will never be the same type as what's on the right side of the 'if'.  Rather, it will be the type of what's INSIDE what's on the right side of the 'if'.

You want:

```
for(int[] s : answers)
```